# How to make header style colors of a PivotItems with MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone, pivot

I want my current header to be blue, and all others to be red. The problem is the headers in my code are not PivotItem.Header, but are of my Type that is binded to the ItemsSource. I know I have to write some property in the ViewModel and bind it to the Foreground property of my textbox, that is the header of my pivotItem but cannot figure it out how?

Here is my XAML:

```
<Pivot Foreground="#FF888888" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{Binding ViewDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewDataSource}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Margin="0, 16, 0, 0" Foreground="?????????" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Light"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <Pivot.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="PivotItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8, 8, 8, 0"/>
            </Style>
        </Pivot.ItemContainerStyle>
    </Pivot>
```

How to write this property in the ViewModel and bind it to Foreground="?????????", to get the desired effect?

I tried this in my Page code-behind, but it does not work because e.AddedItems[0] is not a PivotItem but from my Type, and currentItem is null:

```
private void MyPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (0 < e.AddedItems.Count)
        {
            PivotItem currentItem = e.AddedItems[0] as PivotItem;

            if (null != currentItem)
            {
                if (null != currentItem.Header)
                {
                    (currentItem.Header as TextBlock).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }
            }
        }

        if (0 < e.RemovedItems.Count)
        {
            PivotItem currentItem = e.RemovedItems[0] as PivotItem;

            if (null != currentItem)
            {
                if (null != currentItem.Header)
                {
                    (currentItem.Header as TextBlock).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you add property `color` to the view model already containing the property `id` and binding to that one?

Comment: id is in my Model.. Also It maybe needs some kind of check if the its the current header or not. How to do it in the ViewModel

Comment: You cannot do that there. The foreground set in the `DataTemplate` is for all pivot headers.

Comment: I dont know how to write the property itself and what checks to do, also what type it has to be? Brush, SolidColorBrush, string? How to see what element is current..

Comment: Play with the `Selected` and `Unselected` visual states and the `ColorAnimation` in a PivotHeaderStyle you might create

Comment: I tried in the code-behind with a trick, but it doesnt work. Please see my Edit